# In C#, How can I reuse an HttpClient for multiple services?

Tags: c#, nuget, client, httpclient, reusability

I've created a C# microservice which offers several different (but related) functions.

I am now creating a C# Nuget package for a client which will help other C# microservices to leverage this microservice.  This will include a Service Collection Extension class to facilitate adding the client to those microservices.

In the interest of separating concerns, within the client, I've separated the functionality into three classes:

- SalesforceCacheQuerier
- SalesforceCacheSyncDataManipulator
- SalesforceCacheAsyncDataManipulator

Each of these need to call out to the same server.

As a niave first implementation, I've composed this method:

```
        public static IServiceCollection AddSalesforceClients(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<SalesforceCacheAuthenticationHandler>();
            ConfigureClient(services.AddHttpClient<ISalesforceCacheQuerier, SalesforceCacheQuerier>());
            ConfigureClient(services.AddHttpClient<ISalesforceCacheSyncDataManipulator, SalesforceCacheSyncDataManipulator>());
            ConfigureClient(services.AddHttpClient<ISalesforceCacheAsyncDataManipulator, SalesforceCacheAsyncDataManipulator>());
            return services;
        }

        private static IHttpClientBuilder? ConfigureClient(IHttpClientBuilder? clientBuilder)
            => clientBuilder.ConfigureHttpClient(ConfigureClient)
            .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new SocketsHttpHandler())
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<SalesforceCacheAuthenticationHandler>();

        private static void ConfigureClient(IServiceProvider provider, HttpClient client)
        {
            SalesforceCacheSettings? settings = provider.GetRequiredService<SalesforceCacheSettings>();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(settings.BaseUrl, settings.ApiEndpoint);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = true;
        }
```

However, this generates three separate HttpClients and triples the traffic for the "Identity Server" used to provide Jwt tokens.

How can I refactor this to create and reuse only a single HttpClient?

Comment: You may look at [named or typed http clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and use `IHttpClientFactory`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, thanks for the prompt response, however I'm not clear how to apply this in a way which allows me to include the authentication server (that method in the middle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed was something like this:

```
            services.AddHttpClient(SALESFORCE_CACHE_CLIENT, (provider, client) =>
            {
                SalesforceCacheClientSettings? settings = provider.GetRequiredService<SalesforceCacheClientSettings>();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(settings.BaseUrl, settings.ApiEndpoint);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = true;
            })
                .AddHttpMessageHandler<SalesforceCacheAuthenticationHandler>();

            services.AddHttpClient<ISalesforceCacheQuerier, SalesforceCacheQuerier>(SALESFORCE_CACHE_CLIENT);
            services.AddHttpClient<ISalesforceCacheSyncDataManipulator, SalesforceCacheSyncDataManipulator>(SALESFORCE_CACHE_CLIENT);
            services.AddHttpClient<ISalesforceCacheAsyncDataManipulator, SalesforceCacheAsyncDataManipulator>(SALESFORCE_CACHE_CLIENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpClientFactory and inject it in  `ConfigureServices`
something like `services.AddHttpClient();`
Later wherever you need client object just give `IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory` in the constructor and you can have access to client object by just asking the factory to create a client.

`HttpClient = HttpClientFactory.CreateClient();` in this fashion.

In case if you want to hold the authentication for the clients and reuse it. I would suggest to maintain a dictionary for each request type.

`var HttpClients = new Dictionary<string, HttpClient>();`

`HttpClients.Add(SalesforceCacheQuerierKey, SalesforceCacheQuerierClient);`

//assuming all the auth related headers are added to this client object //SalesforceCacheQuerierClient

and pass these from startup level.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I think perhaps there may be some slight misunderstanding.  I only need one client, but it needs to be consumed by multiple services and it needs a way of authenticating.  I think @Pavel Anikhouski is onto something with his comment above, but I haven't figured out how to apply it yet.